# AngularJs bookmarkable url and query parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to fix one mistake which one of the previous developer has did. Currently in project we have half-bookmarkable pages. Why half? Because if token has expired user will be redirect to resourse where he has to provide his credentials and on success he will be redirect to previous resource which he has used before. Sounds good for now. The problem here is next, some of resources have server side filtering and highly complicated logic which comes in the end to the one object like this:

```
 param = {
        limit: 10,
        offset: 0,
        orderBy: 'value',
        query: 'string query can include 10 more filters'
    };
```

then thru the service it sends a request to the end point

```
var custom = {};
    function data(param) {
        custom.params = param;
        return $http.get('/data_endpoint', custom)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
```

From this part request works fine and response is correct but url isn't. User cannot store current url with search params because url doesn't have it and if user will try to get back to previous page with applied filters he won't be able to do that. 
Also there is interceptor in this application, which add one more query param to every api request, because every api request requires some specific validation. This param is always the same.

I have tried to add `$location.search(param)` exactly to this data service but it breaks the app with infinity loop of login / logout looping, because interceptor stops working and all other request are sending without special query param

Then I thought to add this params inside interceptor like this:

```
config.params.hasOwnProperty('query') ? $location.search(config.params) : $location.search();
```

But it still breaks app to infinity loop.

This method adds query to url but doesn't allow to modify it, so if user applied additional filtering, it doesn't send new modified request but sends old one.

```
  if (config.params.hasOwnProperty('query')){
                for (var key in config.params){
                    $location.search(key, config.params[key])
                }
            }
```

That's why I decided to ask question here, probably somebody gives an advice how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming your using some angular routing you can add `reloadOnSearch:false` to the route configuration, this will cause your calls to `$location.search()` to not reload the page and put you in a loop. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: @ug_ ` .when('/page',{templateUrl:'/views/page/data-list.html',controller:'data',reloadOnSearch:false})` still breaks to infinity loop